# Use datetime to slice dataframe not working

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, datetime, slice

`date = dt.datetime(2020,8,25)`

It works in this way: `df.loc[ df.index > date ]` but not in `df.loc[ date : ]` or in `df[ date : ]`. I have checked that df.index is timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the date as a string for this.

```
df.loc['2020-8-25': ]
```

Comment: actually I found out that it was because index is not monotonically increasing. After sorting index, I can use df[date:] directly